# Argparse functions Python

Tags: python, argparse

How is possible with the code below work for the function test, on foo and bar it work's correctly.

```
import argparse

class Myclass(object):

    def foo(self):
        print 'foo'

    def bar(self):
        print 'bar'

    def test(self,name,place):
        print name, place


class Main(Myclass):
    def __init__(self):
        foo_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        foo_parser.add_argument('method')
        self.args = foo_parser.parse_args()

    def __call__(self, *args, **kws):
        method = self.args.method
        return getattr(self, method)(*args, **kws)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main()

    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I got is below:

```
def __init__(self):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

    for name in dir(self):
        if not name.startswith("_"):
            p = subparsers.add_parser(name)
            method = getattr(self, name)
            argnames = inspect.getargspec(method).args[1:]
            for argname in argnames:
                p.add_argument(argname)
            p.set_defaults(func=method, argnames=argnames)
    self.args = parser.parse_args()

def __call__(self):
    a = self.args
    callargs = [getattr(a, name) for name in a.argnames]
    return self.args.func(*callargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

`test` needs args.  You are not passing any in to the call to `main()`, so there are none to pass in `__call__()`

you probably want to add something like this to `__init__()`:

```
  parser.add_argument('arguments', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)
```

and then pass `main.args.arguments` back into the dynamic call.